# FFMPEG, change default audio track with code

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, libavformat

I have mkv video, and what just change default audio track without remux, encode/decode and other stuff. How it can be done with code?

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;

av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, [videoPath UTF8String], NULL, NULL) != 0) {
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
    return;
}

if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0) {
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
    if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        // so we have audio track info
        // what todo next?
    }
}
avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
```

Comment: ffmpeg won't allow that. You'll have to demux and remux. Use mkvtoolnix or see how it does it.

Comment: refer to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329506/582516)